# yii dynamic cant of instances in one form

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, yii

Hi I'm new using Yii and I'm having a problem, I have two models, modelA and modelB , modelB has a foreing key to modelA, so what I want is in the form of modelA add instances of modelB dinamically. I mean in the form of modelA fill all the fields of modelA and add 3 or 4 instances of modelB, then submit everithing together.
There is any way to do it with yii?

Please an example would be helpful.

Comment: In your `ModelA` controller where you are creating a new ModelA (usually `actionCreate()`), can you not add code to add a new ModelB after `$modelA->save()` returns true?

Answer (score 0):

Well,if i understood you well,i think you should define a new object of Model A in COntroller related to B and injects fields of B into A in the action that is in charge of that process!